Django 5 use of static files with images
I´m trying to a picture to website with help of Django 5 and static files, the website its self is working with no error is diplayed in Django 5 but image is not displayed
Has tried to read the documentation about static files and Django 5
Has tried to change path to location of jpg file
Website is running locally on my machine
HTML:
{% load static %}
<body>
    <img src="{% static 'images\house_of_functions_hawkeye.jpg' %}" 
 alt="">
    <div class="container">
    <h1 id="main__title">Welcome to House of functions</h1>

In settings.py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR =Path(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR =Path(BASE_DIR, "static")
print(STATIC_DIR)

and
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_DIRS = [
STATIC_DIR / "static",
]

Example from my website

In your settings.py you can remove this:
STATIC_DIR = Path(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR / "static",
]

and use this code and i think it'll solve your problem:
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

